# Access a class' private members?

Tags: c++, class, oop

So I have parent class A. Classes B and C inherit from A, however they do not relate to each other. Classes B and C both define their own private members. How can class C access class Bs private members, without inheriting from it ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare `C` as a `friend` of B.

```
class B{
    friend class C;
    // ....
};
```